# How to do a partial map from source in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map only 2 out of 4 properties from an object to the destination type. In my case `DeletedBy` and `DeletedDate`, where as DeletedDate will simply be set to the current UTC date.

```
public class DeleteCommand : IRequest
{
    public string CodePath { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Guid? DeletedBy { get; set; }

    [IgnoreMap]
    public DeleteMode DeleteMode { get; set; } = DeleteMode.Soft;
}
```

This is my current configuration:

```
CreateMap<DeleteCommand, Asset>(MemberList.Source)
    .ForMember(x => x.DeletedDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => DateTime.UtcNow))
    .ForMember(x => x.DeletedBy, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DeletedBy));
```

Running a unit test against this specific mapper configuration gives me 2 errors for a missing mapping:

```
[Fact]
public void MapperConfigShouldBeValid()
{
    _config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

> Unmapped properties: 
>   DeletedDate 
>   DeleteMode

This is confusing me, since the Date is explicitly defined and the DeleteMode is set to be ignored by default. If possible I want to avoid to create another dto to be mapped from a first dto and then to the entity, to be soft-deleted, by setting the audit fields.

Things I've tried so far:

- `IgnoreMapAttribute` as shown above
- `ForSourceMember()`, seems to not support an Ignore method for a source property.

Comment: Could You show how You `Asset` type looks like?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but i get a feeling that You have types for source and destination in wrong order.

Comment: I could, but since all I want to map are the 2 audit fields, does it play a role, if I post 2 fields or 32? It's rather large, so I'd avoid cluttering the question, if I can.

Comment: @GrzegorzSławecki it's `CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>()`, so I guess I've got the order right.

Comment: Looks like `.ForSourceMember(x => x.DeleteMode, y => y.DoNotValidate())` seems to do the trick. I'll write a unit test for it now.

Comment: You could also try to remove the `MemberList.Source` from  `CreateMap` agrument list.

Comment: This will definitely not work, as I will get an exception, telling me I have 30-ish unmapped properties. But since I do not want to map all of those target properties, but only 1 or 2 source properties, I explicitly use this argument.

Comment: I was able to avoid the issue with unmapped properties in `Asset` by adding `.ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore())`. So to sum up, getting rid of `MemberList.Source` and ignoring all other members seems to work for what is my understanding of Your issue.

Comment: Aye, that seems to make the tests happy and lit up green too. Mind giving that as an answer, so I can accept it? I like your approach more then mine - easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by removing `MemberList.Source` from argument list of `CreateMap()` and ignoring all remaining unmapped destination members.

```
CreateMap<DeleteCommand, Asset>()
.ForMember(x => x.DeletedDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => DateTime.UtcNow))
.ForMember(x => x.DeletedBy, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DeletedBy))
.ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore())
```

Same could be achieved by having `CreateMap(MemberList.None)`. This doesn't even require explicitly ignoring all other destination members.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `DeletedDate` as a property solved 50% of my issues, since I don't need it on the source any more.

The other one was updating the map with `ForSourceMember(x => x.DeleteMode, y => x.DoNotValidate())`

This then also works in a quick unit test:

```
[Fact]
public void DeleteMapShouldSetAuditFields()
{
    var asset = new Asset();
    var cmd = new DeleteCommand
    {
        DeletedBy = Guid.NewGuid()
    };

    _mapper.Map(cmd, asset);

    Assert.NotNull(asset.DeletedBy);
    Assert.NotNull(asset.DeletedDate);
    Assert.Equal(cmd.DeletedBy, asset.DeletedBy);
}
```